# Is there a good use for inout parameters?

Tags: .net, calling-convention

IS there a good use for inout (ref in C#, byref (like out parameters) in vb.net) parameters in .NET?
I feel that the confusion caused by a parameter used both as input and as a return value is worse that the increase in the number of parameters for out parameters, or returning an array or returning an custom class.

Comment: Only if you can't tell whether you ave an innie or an outie.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've used it mostly for adapting to legacy code.= (com interop).

I also tend to use it in code that needs to be performant and indicate success:

```
bool PerformSomeReadOperation(SomeInput obj, ref int defaultedOutput) { }
```

where the return value is a notion of success or failure or perhaps an error code and defaultedOutput is a value that comes in with a default value.

Did you know that there is [no real difference between out and ref](http://www.atalasoft.com/cs/blogs/stevehawley/archive/2008/04/18/out-out-damn-ref.aspx) (at least as far as the CLR is concerned)?

Answer (score 6):

The most common use (which still isn't that common, IMO) I've come across is a sort of "modify an existing object, or create one if necessary". For example:

```
public void AppendToBuilder(ref StringBuilder builder)
{
    if (builder == null)
    {
        builder = new StringBuilder();
    }
    builder.Append(/* whatever */);
}
```

`StringBuilder` probably isn't a great example, but it means you can sometimes avoid creating an object when you don't need to:

```
public static string DoSomething(IEnumerable<Foo> foos)
{
    // For an empty collection or where there aren't any
    // frobulating foos, we don't need to create a builder
    StringBuilder builder = null;
    foreach (Foo foo in foos)
    {
        if (foo.Frobulates)
        {
            foo.AppendToBuilder(ref builder);
        }
    }
    return builder == null ? null : builder.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are likely to make a series of calls that modify the same variable.

It doesn't happen much in pointer-based languages like C# though, because you can just pass an object as an 'in' parameter and the called function can call its methods to modify it as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

In some rare cases it can be useful, mostly for performance reasons.

In most cases it can, and in my opinion it should, be avoided by returning an array or a custom class as you mention.

Answer (score 0):

Ref and out parameter passing modes are used to allow a method to alter variables passed in by the method caller.

Each parameter passing mode (ref and out) is designed to suite different programming needs.

The caller of a method which takes an **out parameter** is **not** required to assign to the variable passed as the out parameter prior to the call; however, the method is required to assign to the out parameter before returning.

One way to think of **out** parameters is that they are like additional return values of a method. They are convenient when a method should return **more than one** value.

Do not confuse the concept of passing by reference with the concept of reference types.

The two concepts are not related; a method parameter can be modified by ref regardless of whether it is a value type or a reference type, there is no boxing of a value type when it is passed by reference.

Answer (score 0):

I've used it with an value-type parameter in a graphics routine that printed text to a GDI window in a vertical layout. The inout parameter kept track of the current Y position:

```
WriteString("hello", ref y);
```

rather than

```
y += WriteString("hello", y);
```

Answer (score 0):

Out is good for simple cases which require multiple return values.  This way you don't get confused by "is it a parameter/is it a return value" that `ref` might cause.

```
public void GetStockQuote(
  string stock, 
  out double lastTrade, 
  out DateTime tradeTime, 
  out double change, 
  out double open)
{
  //perform stock magic here
}
```

Comment: Those are all "out" though - the question is about "ref". (I would say that in your example, that's crying out for an encapsulated type.)

Comment: Reread the question... Thought he meant in/out, or both.  And, yes, the example isn't exactly the best way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

I use it when I want to modify a value and think a wrapper class is overkill.

For example

```
if (line[index].StartsWith("X12"))
    ParseX12(lines, ref index, builder); //eats 2 or 4 lines

else if (line[index].StartsWith("A27"))
    ParseA27(lines, ref index, builder); //eats 1 line

else if (line[index].StartsWith("B16"))
    ParseB16(lines, ref index, builder); //eats 1 to 3 lines

else 
    index++; //this line couldn't be parsed, skip to the next one
```

In this example the Parse functions may consume more than one line. Thus they are responsible for correctly updating the index variable.

Answer (score 0):

You've really answered you own question.

If it makes sense to pass data both in and out through a parameter - ie. if the method needs to know the present value and also is expected to update it (or, in the case of a reference type, replace it), then ref is right. It doesn't happen often, but when it does, you know what to use ;-)